# How to save a texture as an image file using libraries related to OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut

The main idea of my code is to draw a scene, supplying both texture and geometric model. The texture is obtained from a ".RAW" and the geometric model comes from a set of triangles from a Delaunay triangulation.

Now, I am able to print the result in the screen and save the displayed result as an image - "Print Screen". I am using freeglut to make it.

The problem is: 
I am using high-resolution input images. But, the output image will have the same resolution as my screen - 1366x768 (that is not compared to the original image - 8956x6708).

Does anyone know a way to save the texture that I am displaying on screen straight to a file? Without using the "Print Screen" approach.

I do not think I can deal with this situation using freeglut.

Comment: Freeglut has nothing to do with that. In the GL, you can use offscreen framebuffers to render to, and you can of course read that back and write it to some image file. 8956x6708 is easily supported by modern GPUs, but even if you hit some limit, you can do a tiled appoach.

Comment: [TR - OpenGL Tile Rendering Library](http://www.mesa3d.org/brianp/TR.html)

Comment: Thanks for the promptly reply. I will study that a little bit more and try to render my results in a "offscreen framebuffer" - FBO, right? 
I found these links that may help: [Framebuffer_Object](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) and [Framebuffer_Object_Examples](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Examples).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to show how I read an image (.raw), inserted its content to a Framebuffer Object and saved to a .ppm file - without a "screen shot".
So, the output image has the same resolution as the input image.

I used the GLEW library to deal with the Framebuffer Object.

I hope it can help some one...

Here you are my code:

*(I deleted part of the code to focus only on the topic of the question. Therefore, there are some variables that do not make sense!)

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#define  GLEW_STATIC

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

#define width       2464
#define height      1648

/// Global Variables
static  GLuint texture;
GLuint  fb = 1; ///Frame-buffer Object

/// Headers
GLuint  raw_texture_load();
void    FBO_2_PPM_file();

/// Functions
GLuint raw_texture_load()
{
    GLuint texture;
    unsigned char *data;
    FILE *file;

    // open texture data
    file = fopen("C:\\Dataset\\1_4.raw", "rb");
    if (file == NULL) return 0;

    // allocate buffer
    data = (unsigned char*) malloc(width * height * 3);

    // read texture data
    fread(data, width * height * 3, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    /// Texture
    // allocate a texture name
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    // select our current texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    // select modulate to mix texture with color for shading
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_DECAL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_DECAL);
    // when texture area is small, bilinear filter the closest mipmap
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    // when texture area is large, bilinear filter the first mipmap
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // texture should tile
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // build our texture mipmapst
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    // free buffer
    free(data);

    return texture;
}

void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushAttrib(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glFlush();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    ///FBO
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    //Attach 2D texture to this FBO
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

    /// Saving the results from the FBO (fb) to a PPM image file
    FBO_2_PPM_file();
}

void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    texture = raw_texture_load();

    render();
}

void FBO_2_PPM_file()
{
    FILE    *output_image;
    int     output_width, output_height;

    output_width = width;
    output_height = height;

    /// READ THE PIXELS VALUES from FBO AND SAVE TO A .PPM FILE
    int             i, j, k;
    unsigned char   *pixels = (unsigned char*)malloc(output_width*output_height*3);

    /// READ THE CONTENT FROM THE FBO
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, output_width, output_height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    output_image = fopen("C:\\Dataset\\output.ppm", "wt");
    fprintf(output_image,"P3\n");
    fprintf(output_image,"# Created by Ricao\n");
    fprintf(output_image,"%d %d\n",output_width,output_height);
    fprintf(output_image,"255\n");

    k = 0;
    for(i=0; i<output_width; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<output_height; j++)
        {
            fprintf(output_image,"%u %u %u ",(unsigned int)pixels[k],(unsigned int)pixels[k+1],
                                             (unsigned int)pixels[k+2]);
            k = k+3;
        }
        fprintf(output_image,"\n");
    }
    free(pixels);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(300, 1);
    glutCreateWindow("...");
    glutHideWindow();

    /// Checking GLEW library
    glewExperimental=TRUE;
    GLenum err=glewInit();

    if(err!=GLEW_OK)
    {
        printf("glewInit failed, aborting.");
        printf("\tError: %s\n\n",glewGetErrorString(err));
        system("pause");
    }

    if (GLEW_EXT_framebuffer_object != GL_TRUE)
    {
        printf("\n\n\t ** Error! GLEW_EXT_framebuffer_object != GL_TRUE \n\n");
        system("pause");
    }

    ///Executing the rendering process
    init();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you just render to a framebuffer this function

```
void glReadPixels(GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, GLvoid *data);
```

will read the pixels rendered and pass the raw data to that point generally a pointer to a unsigned char array.

You can check this documentation [glReadPixels](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) for more information.

Sorry and for save the file there is not one library that save in all formats but i have use [lodepng](http://lodev.org/lodepng/), it save and load png files, that format is the most conformable for hold graphics in my opinion you can check it out.